# Function sqlite3_open_v2 filepath

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I have a problem with sqlite3_open_v2 function. OS is Windows, developing in Qt Creator.

`sqlite3_open("database.db", &db); // works fine`

but

`sqlite3_open_v2("database.db", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, ""); // don't work`

I'm quite sure it's not utf-8 codding problem, cause first function works fine and i tried to change codding in project properties.
Maybe problem is with filepath in first arg. Absolute paths didn't work too.

Anyone had any idea and exmple of using this function?

Comment: What's the error? The mode should be a string like "rw"

Comment: There is no error. Compilation is fine, but function returned code is always SQLITE_ERROR, so datbase is not found.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for answers.

Problem was with last parameter. It must be 0 or NULL instead of ""

That's all, thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

This is probably because the file does not exist in the working directory.
I would add some code to print the path of the current working directory just before calling sqlite3_open_v2 to be sure.

One difference between sqlite3_open and sqlite3_open_v2 with SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE is the first one will create an empty database when no file is found, while the second one will not.

In order to allow the creation of a database with sqlite3_open_v2, you should use:

```
sqlite3_open_v2("database.db", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL );
```

Be sure to have a look at the documentation for more information:
http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html